# Swift delegate as a function parameter

Tags: ios, swift, null, delegates

I created my protocol as below:

```
import Foundation
protocol ITcpCLient: class {
    func OnMessageReceived(_ message: String);
}
```

The class using protocol as below:

```
import Foundation

class tcpConnection {
    var tcpClientdelegate: ITcpCLient?

    init(client: ITcpCLient) {
        self.tcpClientdelegate? = client

        if self.tcpClientdelegate == nil {
            print("tcpClient Delegate is nil!")
        }
    }

    func trigger() {
        tcpClientdelegate?.OnMessageReceived("From Trigger")
    }

}
```

My ViewController Class is below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("viewDidLoad!")
        let myTcpConnection = tcpConnection(client: self)
        myTcpConnection.trigger()
    }


}


extension ViewController: ITcpCLient {

    func OnMessageReceived(_ message: String) {
        print("onMessageReceived")
        print(message)
    }

}
```

The output is: tcpClient Delegate is nil!
If I create delegate without question mark, the code working as expected.But when I use optional type, I cant assign viewcontroller class as a delegate.

Comment: `self.tcpClientdelegate? = client` — does it even compiles?

Comment: @user28434 It does

Comment: Hm, that's some peculiar language construction then.

Comment: One note. mark `tcpClientdelegate` variable as `weak` to avoid retain cycle

Comment: I'm sorry, but SO has too much similar questions. Btw - it's basic language thing. Have u google it first?..

Comment: @VladPulichev, feel free to flag it as duplicate then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `self.tcpClientdelegate` is `nil`  then appending `?` operator will cause  whole statement not to be  run  => which causes that delegate to be un-assinged = nil

```
self.tcpClientdelegate? = client
```

so replace with

```
self.tcpClientdelegate = client
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the `init`:

```
self.tcpClientdelegate? = client
```

The postfix `?` operator will not carry out whatever operation you specified if its operand is `nil`.

Here, `self.tcpClientdelegate` is nil, so the value is not assigned.

From the [Swift Language Reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_optional-chaining-expression):

> Optional-chaining expressions must appear within a postfix expression,
>   and they cause the postfix expression to be evaluated in a special
>   way. **If the value of the optional-chaining expression is nil, all of
>   the other operations in the postfix expression are *ignored* and the
>   entire postfix expression evaluates to nil.**

Just assign it normally to fix the problem, because you don't care about whether `self.tcpClientdelegate` was `nil` or not:

```
self.tcpClientdelegate = client
```